# Comparing lines on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas on which i'm drawing 4 lines. 
I need to then compare the accuracy of those lines drawn against the coordinates of 4 predefined lines.
Can i do this with canvas?

thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JJPA says, give it a try!

One route you could take would be to store the coordinates of the drawn line and the expected line. Each line forms a vector. You can take the [Euclidean distance between the lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) using a simple formula. The closer the distance, the more accurate the lines.

I just wrote this.

```
var expected =  {from: {x:10, y:10}, to:{x:20, y:20}}
var identical = {from: {x:10, y:10}, to:{x:20, y:20}}
var close =     {from: {x:9,  y:9},  to:{x:21, y:21}}
var lessClose = {from: {x:8,  y:13}, to:{x:25, y:15}}

var distance = function(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.from.x - b.from.y, 2) + 
                     Math.pow(a.to.x - b.to.y, 2))
}

console.log("identical", distance(expected, identical))
console.log("close", distance(expected, close))
console.log("lessclose", distance(expected, lessClose))
```

gives

```
identical  0
close      1.4142135623730951
lessclose  5.830951894845301
```

If you don't know which way round the lines are, you can swap start and end points and take the minimum distance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the pixels of your canvas in an rgb-array in javascript:
`var pixelarray= canvas.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data;`
then `pixelarray[0]` as integer is the red-value of the first pixel, `pixelarray[3]` the red-value of the second and so on.
In a canvas of 100px width (pixel-index 0 to 299 in first line), `pixelarray[299]` would be the blue-value of the last pixel in the first line and `pixelarray[300]` the red-value of the first in second line.

Then you could get either the functions representing the 4 lines you want to compare to and do something like

```
function isblack(x,y,width,height){
return pixelarray[(y*width+x)*3]==255&&pixelarray[(y*width+x)*3+1]==255&&pixelarray[(y*width+x)*3+2]==255||x<0||x>width||y<0||y>height;
}
function f(x){return a*x+b;}
var lineblackness=0;
for(var x=0;x<picturewidth;x++)if(isblack(x,f(x),picturewidth,pictureheight))lineblackness++;
if(lineblackness==picturewidth)line_is_drawn();
```

Where fx(x) would represent the line ...

well, if you use a picture or coordinates for the line, it might get easier:

```
getcoord(data){
var ar=new array();
for(var i=0;i<data.length/3;i++)if(data[i*3]==255)ar.push(i);
return ar;
}
var comparecoords=getcoord(comparecanvas.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data);
var thisdata=canvas.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data;
var linehits=0;
for(var i=0;i<comparecoords.length;i++){if(thisdata[comparecoords[i]*3]==255)linehits++;}
if(comparecoords.length==linehits)all_coords_are_hit();
```

Here I only compared the red-value, assuming you have a black&White-image.

If you want to compare lines that aren't exactly fits, you can change the ==255 with a few additional ifs e.g.

```
function isblack(x,y,width,height,blurr,treshhold){
    for(var i=-blurr;i<blurr;i++)if(x-i>0&&x+i<width&&pixelarray[(y*width+(x+i))*3]>=treshhold)return true;
    for(var i=-blurr;i<blurr;i++)if(y-i>0&&y+i<height&&pixelarray[((y+i)*width+(x))*3]>=treshhold)return true;
    return false;
    }
```

This function uses also only red, but uses a treshhold to let also gray be valid. it also accepts a blurr-value for checking in x-direction before/after the pixel and then again in y-direction.

You could also combine the two loops for checking in an rectangle around the pixel.

Changing the `return true` into `return i` will also give you the distance from the pixel you want to check. if you combine the two loops into an i and a j-value, return sqrt(i^2+j^2) and sum all checks up, you can get an indicator how accurate your line is.

To implement sqareroot-error, only comparing the y-distance and summing up the squared distance i^2 should be enough.

Please note that these programs are suggestions, better implementations may exists and my codes could still contain errors.